# Tensorflow training, how to prevent training node deletion

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am using Tensorflow with python for object detection.

I want to start training and leave it for a while and keep all training nodes (model-cpk). Standard Tensorflow training seems to delete nodes and only keep the last few nodes. How do I prevent that?

Please excuse me if this is the wrong place to ask such questions. I would be oblidged if been told a proper place. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `keep_checkpoint_max` flag to `tf.estimator.RunConfig` in `model_main.py`.
You can set it to a very large number to practically save all checkpoints.
You should be warned though that depending on the model size and saving frequency, it might fill up your disk (and therefore crash during training).
You can change saving frequency by the flags `save_checkpoints_steps` or `save_checkpoints_secs` of `RunConfig`. The default is to use `save_checkpoints_secs`, with a default value of 600 (10 minutes).

Comment: Is there a way to do that in the old `legacy/train.py` ? `model_main.py` makes more problems than I can handle.

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but I believe you can use the `max_to_keep` flag of tf.train.Saver in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py#L375. The default is 5, and by setting it to 0 or None, you keep all checkpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can save modelcheckpoints as .hdf5 files are load them again when wanting to predict on test data.
Hope that helps.